# android action bar slide when drawer menu opens

Tags: android, android-actionbar, slide, navigation-drawer

I have android navigation drawer as menu. When it opens (Picture 1) action bar is not moving to the right, I want to have navigation Drawer the whole height, and when you open it, action bar should slide right (Picture 2) as it is in many apps e.g Facebook.

what should I do ?

[image] [image]